# How to clean outdoor traps?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

After my third siege, my outdoors trap corridor is filled with bodies, blood and other sticky icky stuff.

[image: Sticky icky stuff and blood]

This is attracting swarms of flies and generating unhappy thoughts for the dwarfs. I've read that the 'Cleaning' labor only works indoors. How do I get my dwarfs to clean the outdoor traps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have weather enabled and your region permits it, rain will clean any tile it touches.

Likewise, you can get your dwarves to move bodies and the like (and if you're playing dwarf fortress properly, there will be a *lot* of bodies) through the <kbd>o</kbd>rders screen, and then <kbd>r</kbd>efuse. There should be an option of "dwarves grab corpses from outside" change that to "yes", and keep "ignore vermin" on if you wish.

Finally, if you have downloaded an updated version of [DFHack](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=58809.0), *the* Dwarf Fortress memory utility, you can instantly clean all contaminants from the map by running DFClean.

Answer (score 6):

Likely the most exciting solution would be to pump water and then lava into the trap area filling it with obsidian which you could then mine out.

Comment: +1 for being possibly the most FUN solution! although i think just one or the other would be enough to purge the area of all contaminants.

Comment: The lava/obsidian would most likely destroy all his traps, by the way.  Depending on your point of view, this is a positive or a negative.

Comment: Mere technicalities, you shouldn't let something like that stand in the way of some fun with lava.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is probably just to build an overhanging roof, so that the trapped areas count as indoors.

If you don't want to do that, maybe assigning a dwarf with cleaning enabled to a burrow that is over your traps would work.  I tend to doubt, though, that this would bypass the indoor requirement.